# R space proportional between points in x-axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a plot with this code:

```
ex1 <- data.frame(Proc=rep(c("32", "16", "8", "4"), each=4),
                  CX=rep(c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"),4),
                  Time=c(15.58,16.94,23.25,24.11,9.6,10.09,12.32,12.95,5.72,6.11,6.87,6.85,3.51,3.54,3.54,3.54))


ggplot(ex1, aes(x=Proc, y=Time, colour=CX, 
                            shape=CX, linetype=CX, group=CX)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_line() +
    theme_linedraw() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom",axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45), axis.text.y = element_text(angle=0)) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 32)) + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits=c("4", "8", "16", "32"))
```

[The result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPW0Q.png)

So, I want that the numbers in the x-axis have a space proportional, because actually the space between 16 and 32 is the same between 4 and 8.

I'd like to show for x-axis: 4 8 _ 16 _ _ _ 32

I tried with: (no success)

```
scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(seq(4,32,by=4)), limits=c("4", "8", "16", "32"))
```

How can I get that plot? What function I need to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
ex1 <- data.frame(Proc=rep(c("32", "16", "8", "4"), each=4),
                  CX=rep(c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"),4),
                  Time=c(15.58,16.94,23.25,24.11,9.6,10.09,
                         12.32,12.95,5.72,6.11,
                         6.87,6.85,3.51,3.54,3.54,3.54))

ex1$Nproc <- as.numeric(as.character((ex1$Proc)))
ggplot(ex1, aes(x=Nproc, y=Time, colour=CX, 
                shape=CX, linetype=CX, group=CX)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_linedraw() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle=0)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 32)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(4,8,16,32),minor_breaks=NULL)
```

Yields:

[image]